# Javascript get the full URL that redirected to a page

Tags: javascript, html, url

[image: javascript refereer image explained]

Hi there, as you can see on the image, in my webpage I have several pages that can redirect to the same page.
On the example, both pages:

```
example.com/content.html -> example.com/news.html
example.com/files/actual.html -> example.com/news.html
```

I want to enable a button on the page `example.com/news.html` which goes back to the **full source refereer url**

So for example, if user A got redirected to `example.com/news.html` through `example.com/content.html` his Go back button should point to the source URL -> `example.com/content.html`

I have tried the JS property

```
var referrer = document.referrer;
console.log(referrer);
```

But It only returns the domain name `example.com` and not the full URL `example.com/content.html`

Any thank is appreciated.

Comment: `document.referrer` serves your purpose, but it doesn't work for Internet Explorer versions earlier than IE9. And if you try to go back then it will redirect to news as there is a redirection.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you need. If you always have a redirection you can use :

```
window.history.go(-2);
```

Otherwise, you may have to manipulate the parameter using history informations.

Full documentation : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API

Comment: More than a "direct redirect" is an <a> link redirect that when the user clicks, sends them to the /news.html page.  Thanks for the info anyways.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for is not possible.   In modern browsers, a redirect does not replace the referrer, nor does the redirect appear in `window.history`.   Using client side JavaScript, there is no way to tell that the user came through a redirect as opposed to clicking on a link that brought them to the page directly.

As a workaround you could change the redirect to add a parameter.  `example.com/content.html` could redirect to `example.com/news.html?from=content.html`  Then the JavaScript on `news.html` could look at the URL parameter to determine which page redirected.

Alternately, you could use server side solutions.  Your server's access log would have a record of redirects.  You could examine this log file to determine which page redirected.